# UI Message default value in Liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, taglib

Does anybody know, if in Liferay is possibility to use default value in ui message ? I mean I have two files .properties with translations, for example: en.properties:

```
welecome=Hallo everybody
someKey=
```

,and default.properites

```
welecome=Hallo everybody
someKey=value of some key
```

I want to achieve, that if I use:

```
<liferay-ui:message key="welcome" />
<liferay-ui:message key="someKey" />
```

with English language (where there is no translation for key 'someKey'), the displayed value will be:

```
Hallo everybody
value of some key
```

I mean, when there is no translation for some key, liferay portlet will use value from default properties file.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the standard naming conventions, you typically have files like `Language.properties` and `Language_en.properties`. When english language is displayed, but the entry is not contained in `Language_en.properties`, I expect the value from `Language.properties` to be shown.

However, in your case you define `someKey` as an empty value, which means that it's defined as exactly this.

Moreover, Liferay offers a "Language Builder" tool that you can run during development time (in the plugins-sdk just run `ant build-lang`. It will create configured language files automatically, automatically copying the values from the original file if they are not yet contained in the translated file.

If you have api credentials for bing, it can also use these to get an automatically translated value for various languages, but I'm not a big fan of these. Actually, I'm quite annoyed by automatic translations.

Comment: Yeah, thank You so much. I didn't get the idea, that empty string isn't null for Liferay properties file. regards